# Define additional variables for file name pattern in Dbeaver?

Tags: sql, sybase, dbeaver

While exporting the resultset i could only find 2 variables that can be used to name a file(table and timestamp).[image]

Does anyone know if custom variables/patterns can be created? I looked for some documentation online, however I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 7):

On DBeaver 5.2.4, there is a tooltip when you hover your cursor to the "File name pattern" textfield. It says, allowed variables are:  `${datasource}, ${catalog}, ${schema}, ${table}, ${timestamp}, ${date}, and ${project}`.

I wish it could help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was more interested in custom variables.Anyway, i went ahead with whatever variables were available in that version.

Answer (score 3):

Those options have changed to:

```
${host}
${database}
${table}
${date}
${timestamp}
```

v6.1.5

Comment: ${shemma} is posible ?

Comment: Try using ${schema}

Comment: I try but not work