# DBeaver's "Script title pattern" option lacks "Project" entry

Tags: ide, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver Community edition **Version 21.1.1.202103210824** (Release date 21 June 2021) for **Windows 10**.

In the menu Window > Preferences > Editors > SQL Editor > Scripts the section "Resources" allows the user to set a "Script title pattern" for the scripts currently open in the editor. It offers a number of placeholders such as `${filename}` and `${schema}`.

[I know for a fact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880029) that `${project}` is also supported. I have several Git repositories that I've imported as Projects and I the `${project}` placeholder would show the Project to which the script belongs. However, I do not see that option in my DBeaver.

Here are the options I see:

[image: My "Script title pattern" options]

Any idea why is that? I tried messing around with the Perspective options. Basically anything is enabled, but the issue persists. The web and the DBeaver user guide aren't offering any help on this specific issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Pattern `${projectName}` showed up after updating to **Version 23.0.4.202305071722**.